# Measured my PCB with Handheld LCR Meter - can you tell me anything?

Tags: pcb, signal-integrity, power-integrity

This is a 5x4cm 8-layer PCB. It has 2 sets of dedicated VCC/GND planes plus ground plane polygons on top and bottom. It is not high speed. The top digital speed is 1Mhz SPI. It has 3 micros running on their internal oscillators. However, I have noise (spikes, overshoot and undershoot) on my i2c clock and data lines running them at only 100kHz -to different parts. Do you see anything unusual in these numbers? Are these normal and expected for a design like this? The numbers are simple ground/vcc measurements. I am reading about power integrity. I have no dc-dc converters, but the board is powered externally.

C 100Hz  12uF

Z 100Hz  135ohms -74

L 100kHz 1.7uH 15 degrees

Z 100kHz 0.9ohms 90 degrees

DCR 60kohm

It looks normal to me, maybe good. Maybe not enough bypass. I didn't measure DC though.

Comment: Are you not supposed to add series termination resistor of 22 ohms or so at each end point? Usually equal to trace impedance. They prevent ringing from the sharp rise/fall times of todays logic.

Comment: Totally didn't think I needed that. I designed in a microphone and headphone and used 51ohm series resistors for those. The i2c pullups are 1.5k, could those lower-end values contribute?

Comment: Could I be getting an inductive kick from the L at 100kHz?

Comment: You have 'Z' as being 135 ohms. Is that your trace impedance? Normally there is a dampening resistor at each end of the trace, just like RS485 or PCIe.

Comment: 'L' should not be in the circuit unless your talking about trace inductance. If so all the more reason to use the proper dampening resistors. You mentioned top speed is a 1 MHZ SPI link. Your board is slow but the logic still has fast rise/fall times.

Comment: Most likely your spikes are measurement errors with inductive probe ground lead length.

Comment: 8 layers!  at 1MHz it should be possible on a single layer board.  it could be you're missing some decoupling capacitors, but with all those ground and vcc planes, you shouldn't need many.

Comment: Sparky256 - I touched the LCR meter (Agilent U1733C) to a gnd and vcc point (3.3V), to test the entire power and ground circuit. I used the 100Hz and 100kHz settings and measured C,L and Z, thinking this would be useful. I think the consensus of dampening resistors may be the fix for my next board. I needed 8 layers for routing. There are a ton of parts, lots of AFE's, and USB.